# Confusion with Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to learn about makefile, mainly to understand a makefile that I'm using, but am getting thrown by what are probably simple things. The section of my makefile that confuses me looks like this:

```
SUBS = dir1 dir2 dir3

depend clean:
         @-X=`pwd`;\
         for i in $(SUBS);\
         cd $$X/$$i;\
         done
```

What does "@-X=`pwd` do? I gather that it somehow assigns the value of the present directory to X, but I have no idea how to read the "@-" syntax.

Also, why do X & i need to be prepended with '$$' instead of just '$'? I've experimentally verified that both $'s are necessary, but would've thought that only one should be needed to replace each with their value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have no idea how to read the "@-" syntax.

Just read it from left to right :-) Kidding aside, "@" at the beginning of a line tells make not to echo the line before executing it; "-" tells it to ignore errors

> X & i need to be prepended with '$$' instead of just '$'?

Because make itself has variables that are accessed via $, but in this case the rule uses shell variables, which are also accessed by $. The $$ is just an escape, so the shell command that gets executed contains $X, instead of the content of the makefile variable X which is probably empty.

Comment: OK - so if I'm understanding correctly, "X=`pwd'" would assign the value of the present working directory to X and print it out. "@X=`pwd`" does the same thing, but without giving me a running commentary in stdout. "@-X=`pwd`" is a little superfluous, since I don't see 'pwd' giving rise to many errors. But why is "X" different than "SUBS", which inly needs one $ to be accessed? Is "SUBS" a reserved word?

Comment: Hold on ... I think I get it. SUBS is only being read by make, so it needs only a single $, but X is being read by the shell, so it needs 2 $'s, one for make & one for the shell.....

Comment: The printing isn't quite correct, it would not print pwd, it would print the entire command line that is passed to the shell. About the variables: yes, there are variables in "make" and variables in the shell. If you look at the lines you'll notice they are all connected with \, so they are actually all in the same shell since it's just one big shell command line. That's why it can use shell variables too.

Comment: If you just remove the @ and invoke "make clean", it should echo one large command line with $SUBS expanded and $$X 'reduced' to just $X. That's what's executed in the shell then.